# iOS: Property 'tableView' not found

Tags: ios, xcode, tableview, reloaddata

My function `[ViewController.tableView reloadData]` does not work, although I implemented `@class ViewController` in the .h file and imported `#import "ViewController.h"` in the .m file.

What am I doing wrong??

--- EDIT ---

Here's my .h file:

```
@class XMLAppDelegate, XMLProductDetailView;

@interface XMLViewController : UITableViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate, XMLImageDownloaderDelegate> {

    NSMutableDictionary *imageDownloadsInProgress; 

    XMLAppDelegate *appDelegate;
    XMLProductDetailView *productDetailView;
    IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchBar;
    IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableDictionary *imageDownloadsInProgress;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchBar;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

- (void)imageDidLoad:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

@end
```

But notice: when I include `IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;`, it hides an instance variable.

Comment: Is "tableView" an IBOutlet that you've connected in IB?

Comment: define 'does not work'. Does the compiler complain? Is there some kind of runtime error? Does nothing happen?

Comment: if I do so, Xcode says it would hide the instance variable tableView (I am using UITableViewCell)

Comment: @dandan78 Xcode means there is no property 'tableView' in the ViewConroller..

Comment: @Alexis Could you edit your question to include the relevant parts of your .h file?

Comment: @dandan78 please have a look :)

Comment: I don't see delegates for UITableView

Comment: I try to include some parts of LazyTableImages, it's a free Apple-Project. there `[ViewController.tableView reloadData]` works fine. could be why I am using storyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ViewController it is class name. You should init instance variable of this class

```
ViewController *vc = [[ViewController  alloc] init];
```

then push it on navigation controller (if it present)

```
vc.myDataForTable = [NSArray .....]; //for example

[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

release vc if arc is not used

```
[vc release];
```

Comment: thank you NeverBe for your input. But my intention is to reload my data in the tableView, not to push my ViewController :)

Comment: OK, paste all code please, init of ViewController  and call [ViewController.tableView reloadData]

Comment: For anyone with similar problems this answer is the basis on which you should begin playing with the tableView property of the ViewController instance vc. See @sosborn's answer and comments for more info.

Answer (score 4):

UITableViewController already has a property named tableView. Rename your property to something like myTableView and you should be OK.

Comment: `self.tableView` accesses this built in table view. `[self.tableView reloadData];` should do the trick.

Comment: @ipwnstuff the tableView is not in the same ViewController :S

Comment: You should refer to @NeverBe's answer for instantiating the ViewController, use `ViewController *vc = [[ViewController  alloc] init];` to instantiate and `[vc.tableViewName reloadData];`.

Comment: AlexisW - you seem to be really confused. If you look at the code you posted, you have an IBOutlet property in a UITableViewController. What do you mean that the tableview is not in the same viewController? I think that @ipwnstuff leading you in the right direction.

Comment: I started getting confused too. Eh.

Comment: I'm still not entirely sure what was going, but I'm glad your code is working!